# Migrei o meu site de http para https e perdi os comentários do Facebook

Tags: facebook, https

Eu estava fazendo alguns testes recentemente no meu site no blogger e quando eu ativei o `https` no meu site, perdi os comentários do Facebook.

Como faço para corrigir isso?

Comment: O facebook salva o link completo do seu site, mano, se mudar qualquer coisa na estrutura da url os comentários vão sumir.

Answer (score 3):

**Conforme a [documentação do facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#faq_1149655968420144)**, não é possível mover as curtidas, compartilhamentos ou comentários diretamente para a nova URL, mas você pode usar a URL antiga como a fonte canônica para o número de curtidas ou compartilhamentos na nova URL.

### Informações básicas

Ao resolver a qual URL uma ação de curtida ou compartilhamento deve ser atribuída, o Facebook usa um processo para resolver a URL canônica da URL que está sendo carregada. Quando uma URL é carregada, o rastreador procura por:

- Um Redirecionamento HTTP 301 ou 302
- O uso de uma tag do [**open graph og:url**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects/#selfhosted) na página
- O uso de `rel=canonical`, conforme descrito no [**RFC 6596**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6596). (O rastreador do Facebook oferece suporte apenas a conteúdo, não a cabeçalhos HTTP.)

Se qualquer um desses métodos resultar em uma URL diferente da URL carregada originalmente, a URL especificada será considerada a "URL canônica" da URL original. Se necessário, o rastreador seguirá uma cadeia de redirecionamentos para encontrar a URL canônica.

Todas as curtidas e compartilhamentos serão atribuídos à URL canônica da URL carregada.

### Exemplos

> Dica: Use nosso [depurador](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) para ver o que o Facebook vê quando rastreia sua página.

Ao controlar a URL canônica, você pode mover o conteúdo de uma URL para outra e manter as contagens de curtidas e compartilhamentos, contanto que você permita ao Facebook continuar resolvendo a nova URL na antiga. Isso pode ser feito com um entre dois métodos:

Adicione uma tag `og:url` à nova URL apontando para a URL antiga (Preferido)
Em sua nova URL, você deve incluir um link para a URL antiga. Por exemplo, se a sua nova URL tiver `https://example.com/new-url` e a URL antiga era `https://example.com/old-url`, inclua este trecho em `new-url`:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="https://example.com/old-url" />
```

No **seu caso**, sua url antiga era algo como `http://foobar.blogspot.com`, agora esta como `https://foobar.blogspot.com`, então no `og:url` faça isto:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://foobar.blogspot.com" />
```

O uso desse método indica ao nosso rastreador que a URL canônica está no local antigo, e o rastreador a usará para gerar o número de curtidas e compartilhamentos na página. Curtidas e compartilhamentos novos continuarão a ser agregados também na URL antiga.

Isso também exige que a URL antiga ainda processe um documento com tags do **Open Graph** e retorne uma resposta HTTP 200, pelo menos quando carregado pelo rastreador do Facebook. Se você quiser que outros clientes sejam redirecionados ao visitar a URL, envie sua resposta 301 HTTP a todos os clientes do rastreador que não forem do Facebook. A URL antiga deve conter sua própria tag `og:url` que aponta para si mesma.

> Saiba como reconhecer o rastreador do Facebook no [Guia de melhores práticas de compartilhamento.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#crawl)

Este método também funcionará com `rel=canonical`, mas há preferência por `og:url`.

---

### Redirecione o rastreador do Facebook para a URL antiga

Outro método de conseguir isso é redirecionar o rastreador do Facebook para a URL antiga sempre que ele visitar a nova URL. Assim como o método descrito acima, a URL antiga deve ser um documento válido com cabeçalhos do Open Graph. E se você quiser incluir um redirecionamento na URL antiga, o rastreador do Facebook não deverá ser redirecionado quando visitar a URL antiga.

Comment: top!! valeu.. nao sabia

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, com a URL antiga, a página usou as propriedades da outra .

Comment: @DavidAugustus legal! Poderia marcar a resposta como correta então ? Obrigado!

Comment: Sim, mas pedir upvote é contra as regras do site hein.

Comment: O certo é colocar só // no url, sempre.. sem http e sem https , ok /

Comment: Uai eu ja tinha votado ja viu

Comment: @DavidAugustus aonde exatamente eu pedi upvote? Poderia mostrar? A única coisa que vejo no meu comentário é marcar "como correta" (leia: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/3635), porque na época eu me confundi, pensei que você era o autor da pergunta.

Comment: @DavidAugustus outra coisa, você está errado, em OPenGraph não se usa `//`, pois justamente é para ser "canonical". Pode conferir na documentação: https://ogp.me/#url (*All valid URLs that utilize the https:// or https:// protocols*)